# For a JTextField, how do I set text from another class?

Tags: java

I have looked around other threads and can't find a working solution.

My program reads a file, splits up each word in a line and stores in an array. If what is searched for is in array[0], then I would like to output the array into its corresponding text fields.

I am trying to test it by just setting the text for 1 text field (ID text field) but the text field is not being populated with text. This is my code so far:

**GUI - StudentUI**

```
public class StudentUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form StudentUI
 */
public StudentUI() {
    initComponents();
    saveBtn.setVisible(false);
}

final String FILENAME = "Students.txt";

private void initComponents() {

    searchTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    idLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    titleLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    forenameLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    surnameLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    address1Lbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    address2Lbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    postcodeLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    numberLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    birthLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    idTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    forenameTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    surnameTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    address1Txt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    address2Txt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    postcodeTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    numberTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    birthTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    searchBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
    searchLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    titleCombo = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    addBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
    editBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
    deleteBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
    saveBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    idLbl.setText("ID");

    titleLbl.setText("Title");

    forenameLbl.setText("Forename");

    surnameLbl.setText("Surname");

    address1Lbl.setText("Address 1");

    address2Lbl.setText("Address 2");

    postcodeLbl.setText(" Postcode");

    numberLbl.setText("Phone Number");

    birthLbl.setText("Date of Birth (DD/MM/YYYY)");

    searchBtn.setText("Search");
    searchBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            searchBtnActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });


public void setTextField(JTextField jTF, String value) {
    jTF.setText(value);
}

private void searchBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    int count = Search.totalLines(FILENAME);
    Search.linear(FILENAME, count, searchTxt.getText());
}                                         

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new StudentUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton addBtn;
private javax.swing.JLabel address1Lbl;
private javax.swing.JTextField address1Txt;
private javax.swing.JLabel address2Lbl;
private javax.swing.JTextField address2Txt;
private javax.swing.JLabel birthLbl;
private javax.swing.JTextField birthTxt;
private javax.swing.JButton deleteBtn;
private javax.swing.JButton editBtn;
private javax.swing.JLabel forenameLbl;
private javax.swing.JTextField forenameTxt;
private javax.swing.JLabel idLbl;
private javax.swing.JTextField idTxt;
private javax.swing.JLabel numberLbl;
private javax.swing.JTextField numberTxt;
private javax.swing.JLabel postcodeLbl;
private javax.swing.JTextField postcodeTxt;
private javax.swing.JButton saveBtn;
private javax.swing.JButton searchBtn;
private javax.swing.JLabel searchLbl;
private javax.swing.JTextField searchTxt;
private javax.swing.JLabel surnameLbl;
private javax.swing.JTextField surnameTxt;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> titleCombo;
private javax.swing.JLabel titleLbl;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**Search Class**

```
public class Search {

public static int totalLines(String filename) {
    int n = 0;
    String currentLine;
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            n = n + 1;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    return n;
}

public static void linear(String filename, int lines, String searchItem) {
    String currentLine;

    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] array = new String[lines];
            array = currentLine.split(",");
            if (array[0].equals(searchItem)) {
                StudentUI student = new StudentUI();
                student.setTextField(student.idTxt, array[0]);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

}
```

Comment: *It's not working* - you'll need to elaborate a little on what's not working. And perhaps shorten your code to a [mcve]

Comment: Okay, I will edit the code now. What isn't working is that nothing occurs - the text field does not set.

Comment: Don't create a new GUI every time you need to set the value. You need to set the value to the existing instance. This can be done if you alter the method signature like following: `linear(String filename, int lines, String searchItem, StudentUI student)`. Then you only have to remove then line `StudentUI student = new StudentUI();` and it should work

Comment: Use getter/setter methods. Like `public void setIdText(String s){idTxt.setText(s);}`

Answer (score 2):

You've a big problem here at (A):

```
public static void linear(String filename, int lines, String searchItem) {
    String currentLine;

    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] array = new String[lines];
            array = currentLine.split(",");
            if (array[0].equals(searchItem)) {
                StudentUI student = new StudentUI();  // ****** (A) ******
                student.setTextField(student.idTxt, array[0]);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ****** (B) ******
    }
}
```

You're creating a `new StudentUI()` object -- a **new** one, one completely different from the StudentUI that is already displaying, and so setting the state of its JTextField will have no effect on the currently displayed StudentUI object.

A wrong solution is to make the JTextField variable static -- don't do this as you'd be throwing out the OOP baby with the bath water by doing this.

A better solution is to pass a reference to the *currently displayed* StudentUI object to his method, so that you can change the state of the object of interest.

---

Other problem at (B) -- don't ignore exceptions in this way, since by doing this, if your code crashes, you won't know why.

---

So one way to solve this is to give the linear method a StudentUI parameter:

```
public static void linear(StudentUI student, String filename, int lines, String searchItem) {

    String currentLine;

    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] array = new String[lines];
            array = currentLine.split(",");
            if (array[0].equals(searchItem)) {
                //  StudentUI student = new StudentUI();  // ****** (A) ******
                student.setTextField(student.idTxt, array[0]);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStacktrace();  // ****** (B) *******
    }
}
```

And then call it, passing `this` into the method as the first parameter.

Also, notice that I'm now printing the exception's stacktrace so that I can see if/when an exception is thrown, what caused it and where.

Comment: Okay great, thankyou for the help! I have now realised at that:    student.setTextField(student.idTxt, array[0]); // the idTxt is underlined saying it has private access. What method would you recommend me use rather than setting the access to public?

Comment: @Andenter: one question per question here. But you're now asking about most basic Java concepts, and not to sound high and mighty and all, but you need to learn these concepts well to continue. Please check the Java tutorials about this last problem, especially on how to create and use public setter and getter methods.

Comment: Ah okay, apologies. As you can clearly tell I am a beginner. Thanks for the previous help.